# Service Now Api integration using client side script

Tags: api, soap-client, servicenow

I tried to integrate external soap based api using servicenow client side scipt options. My intention is to initiate an external api call when an incident is created. 
But i am getting uncaught reference error sn_ws is not defined exception.

```
 function onSubmit() {
    try {
     var s = new sn_ws.SOAPMessageV2('global.IQTrack', 'VerifyApiKey');

     s.setStringParameterNoEscape('VerifyApiKey.apiKey', 'dfghdhgdjh');

     var response = s.execute();

     var responseBody = response.getBody(); 

     var status = response.getStatusCode();

    }
    catch(ex) { 
     alert(ex);
    }
 }
```

Is this the way to initiate api call? If it is so why it is getting sn_ws is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

That's because sn_ws is a server-side API.

You need to either use GlideAjax, or a client-side webservices API such as XMLHttpRequest. 
You can find an excellent article on GlideAjax, here: http://snprotips.com/blog/2016/2/6/gliderecord-client-side-vs-server-side

If your aim is to initiate the message once a ticket is created, then you should definitely be doing this server-side, not in a client script.

Answer (score 0):

I hope,sn_ws is a server-side API.
I think `GlideAjax` method will help you to get rid of this issues.
please go through below links,I think it will help you to sort out this issues.

http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=GlideAjax#gsc.tab=0

And alternative is use client-side webservices API like `XMLHttpRequest`